# Combine objects in a list by fields of the objects

Tags: c#

I have a list of BillArticle objects this class look something like this:

```
public class BillArticle
{
    public int ArticleID { get; set; }

    public string ArticleName { get; set; }

    public double ArticleQuantity { get; set; }

    public double ArticlePrice { get; set; }
}
```

So i have List contaning lets say 10 objects and i would like to merge this objects by repeating ArticleID and ArticlePrice.

So my problem is this: I want to go throught the list and if there is 2 or more objects with same ArticleID and same Price to merge them(to sum the ArticleQuantity). I have been pounding my head for a while now and will be greatfull if anyone can give me a hand. Thanks for the help in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ is great for this sort of work :) It sounds like you might want something like:

```
var merged = list.GroupBy(x => x.ArticleID)
                 .Select(g => new BillArticle { 
                             ArticleID = g.Key,
                             ArticleName = g.First().ArticleName,
                             ArticleQuantity = g.Sum(x => x.ArticleQuantity),
                             ArticlePrice = g.First().ArticlePrice
                         });
```

That's assuming you are confident that the price and name of all the articles will be the same. If not, you should consider how you want to handle that situation.

If you need `merged` to be a `List<BillArticle>`, just add `.ToList()` at the end.

EDIT: As noted in Andy's answer, you can group by article ID and article price using an anonymous type. You'd still need to think about the article name. If an article ID really *is* an identifier, I'd expect the name and price to be the same anyway, but it depends on your business rules.

Comment: +1, wow, that was fast. I haven't even finished projection in Select clause.

Comment: @Jordan. I tried to fit the changes to show how to group by both `ArticleId` and `ArticlePrice` in a comment, but it wouldn't fit, I've added a second answer. JonSkeet's first answer is spot on for grouping by `ArticleId` only. @JonSkeet, I hope that's ok with you.

Comment: @AndyBrown: I'm never going to object to someone adding another answer - especially as I apparently misread the question :)

Comment: @JonSkeet. But you're JonSkeet. When you answer a question, [the question changes to match your answer](http://www.chucknorrisfacts.com/node/26441)!!

Answer (score 2):

*[JonSkeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) has already answered this perfectly for grouping by a single property. I tried to explain grouping by two or more properties in a comment and it wouldn't fit, so I'll do it as a separate answer.*

`ArticlePrice` is something that you could expect to change over time - a fact of capitalism that often makes our perfect code less perfect. You mentioned:

> 2 or more objects with same ArticleID and same Price

This is a slightly different requirement, so depending on the question you are answering:

- if you `GroupBy(x => x.ArticleID)` you are answering "how many items with `ArticleID` 12345 did I sell";
- if you group by both id and price you are answering "how many items with `ArticleID` 12345 did I sell when they were at $10, when they were at $20 ...".

The change to [JonSkeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s code is simple for the second case (I've noted the changes with `// changed here`
 comments):

```
var merged = list.GroupBy(x => new {x.ArticleID, x.ArticlePrice }) // changed here
                 .Select(g => new BillArticle { 
                     ArticleID = g.Key.ArticleID, // changed here
                     ArticleName = (string)g.First().ArticleName,
                     ArticleQuantity = g.Sum(x => x.ArticleQuantity),
                     ArticlePrice = g.Key.ArticlePrice // changed here
                 });
```