# List of objects with duplicate keys combine field into comma list

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a Linq To SQL result which is a list of objects representing staff. There are duplicate staff records if the staff member is registered to more than one location. In the case of multiple staff records, I need to comma separate those locations in "location" so that I now have one staff record.
Here is the select statement:

```
staff = query...
select new UserModel
{
   sourceId= stf.STAFF_GU,
   location = loc.LOCATION_GU.ToString(),
   userName = user.LOGIN_NAME,
   email = person.EMAIL
}).ToList();
```

I am stuck on how to get my final list where each user has one row, and the location is a comma list of that user's locations.

I tried JonSkeet's solution from this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16692544/combine-objects-in-a-list-by-fields-of-the-objects) but I don't know how to turn the group of locations to a list of strings.

```
var merged = staff.GroupBy(x => x.sourceId)
                 .Select(g => new UserModel
                 {
                     sourceId = g.Key,
                     userName = g.First().userName,
                     location = g.**DO_WHAT_TO_COMBINE_LOCATIONS**(x => x.location),
                     email = g.First().email
                 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `string.Join()` method probably like

```
location = string.Join(",",g.Select(x => x.location))
```

Comment: Oh my. Thank you for that.